# PHP - Retrieve data using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem retrieving data from a database. So I have a page that has a search box. A user types in an item number and gets redirected to a single item page with transferring that number using form . Then a script picks that number and shows only a result where that number equals a result number. **PROBLEM:** everything works well if that number consists of numbers only. If we add letters it goes to "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object". In a database I set this be TEXT, not NUMBER.

Here is the code on a single item page:

So first it gets that number from top URL (part.php?partnumber=WB20K10023+):

```
$item_number = $_GET['item_number'];
$allItems = fetchAllItems($item_number);
```

Then it runs this function:

```
function fetchAllItems($item_number) {      
        global $mysqli,$db_table_prefix; 
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT            
            *
            FROM ".$db_table_prefix."items
            WHERE
            item_number = $item_number
            LIMIT 1
            ");
        $stmt->execute(); // <- This line shows in an error_log
        $stmt->bind_result($id);
        while ($stmt->fetch()){
            $row[] = array('id' => $id);
        }
        $stmt->close();
        return ($row);      
    }
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless. Other than that, you're simply missing a pair of inverted commas

Comment: `partNumber = '$partNumber'`. Strings need to be enclosed in quotes. Since you are using `mysqli` and `prepare()` you really should be using a placeholder `partNumber = ?` and `$stmt->bind_param('s',$partNumber);`.

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740 - the code is not correctly using parameterized queries, the `$identifier` is interpolated and does *not* represent a placeholder.

Comment: @Art Adding the quotes results in poor code.. make sure to properly bind.

Answer (score -1):

If your partNumber field in the MySQL table is of string/text/varchar data type, then in the query string, you should write `partNumber = '$partNumber'` instead of writing `partNumber = $partNumber`.

**Edit:**

Need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent sql injection. So it would be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_prefix."items
WHERE
item_number = '{mysql_real_escape_string($item_number)}'"
```

For MySQLi though, `prepare` function would do the escape work to prevent SQL injections. Only the inverted commas would help like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_prefix."items
WHERE
item_number = '$item_number'"
```

Comment: While that may "fix" the problem it is a poor approach that leads to SQL Injection. The OP should use placeholders, especially considering that the code *already* uses MySQLi.